# Multiple kafka topics in publishKafka processor in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am trying to have three different data sources from Twitter(GetTwitter Processor) in Apache Nifi and only one PublishKafka_0_10 processor.
Can I put data from three different data sources to single Publish kafka processor in separate topics?

if yes can anyone provide me any links for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do two things in this case:

1. You can either use three `PublishKafka_0_10` processors and configure them with three different topic names individually.
2. If you want to stick with only one `PublishKafka_0_10` processor then you can leverage the `ExpressionLanguage` support that the `Topic` property offers in `PublishKafka_0_10` processor.

In the latter case, you need to connect the three `GetTwitter` processors to three `UpdateAttribute` processors individually. Configure `UpdateAttribute` processor and add a new property, say `topicName` and give them the relevant topic names. For ex, if you want the first `GetTwitter` processor to write to `politics` topic, configure it with that name. Similarly for the other two, give the relevant names. Then connect the three `success` relationships from the `UpdateAttribute` processors to the `PublishKafka_0_10` processor. Configure the `PublishKafka_0_10` and set the `Topic` property to `${topicName}`